# Google ads api list all accounts and their campaigns

Tags: google-ads-api

I am totally new to google ads, I have a google ads account setup. I have a customer id (which I believe is the parent account id), under this I have a lot of 'Accounts' (url: ads.google.com/aw/accounts) setup. Every account have a list of campaigns. I want to prepare a report to fetch all campaigns and there settings. I am using postman to hit google apis (googleads.googleapis.com/v8).

I want to know what apis I can use to list all customer accounts and their campaigns?

Answer (score 0):

Using the rest API for this sort of operation is not advised. It's expensive and there's an extremely tight limit.

It's advised to use the gRPC client libraries as they use search operations. You can learn more here: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/start

Each of the client libraries has a robust set of examples and sample code that demonstrates exactly what you're trying to achieve (called list_accessible_accounts or similar). If you let me know what language you're using I can point you to the correct one.